# Get the value from two tables, one of which is Many-to-many

Tags: postgresql

I want to get only those v.v_name, to which mtm.can_id = 2 is not attached. How to do it?

P.S. v.id = mtm.vac_id

Vacancy table:

```
+----+--------------------------+
| Id |          v_name          |
+----+--------------------------+
|  1 | Registered Nurse         |
|  2 | Pharmacist               |
|  7 | Dentist                  |
|  8 | Computer Systems Analyst |
|  9 | Physician                |
+----+--------------------------+
```

M-t-M table :

```
+----+--------+--------+
| Id | can_id | vac_id |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |      1 |      1 |
|  2 |      1 |      2 |
|  3 |      2 |      2 |
|  4 |     37 |      2 |
|  5 |     37 |      1 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+---+--------------------------+
| 7 | Dentis
| 1 | Registered Nurse         
| 8 | Computer Systems Analyst 
| 9 | Physician                
+---+--------------------------+
```

Comment: I did not have enough rating to insert the image on another = (But I understood the remark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
select * from vacancy where id not in (select distinct  vac_id from mtm where can_id = 2)
```

Comment: if can id more then one then it will not work cause not in need to comma separate

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get all result which not mtm.can_id = 2 then check this but not tested

```
select * from v_table where id not in (select distinct vac_id from mtm_table where mtm.can_id = 2)
```

Comment: Did not work = (returned: Registered Nurse, Registered Nurse, Pharmacist, Pharmacist

Comment: is it not working?i have checked and working fine for me

Comment: sry, no=( Need 15 reputation. Now i have 10 =(